# PL SQL - Join 2 tables and return max from right table

Tags: max

Trying to retrive the MAX doc in the right table.

```
SELECT   F43.PDDOCO, 
     F43.PDSFXO, 
     F43.PDLNID,
     F43.PDAREC/100 As Received, 
     F431.PRAREC/100,
     max(F431.PRDOC)

FROM     PRODDTA.F43121 F431
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODDTA.F4311 F43
      ON 
          F43.PDKCOO=F431.PRKCOO 
      AND F43.PDDOCO=F431.PRDOCO 
      AND F43.PDDCTO=F431.PRDCTO 
      AND F43.PDSFXO=F431.PRSFXO 
      AND F43.PDLNID=F431.PRLNID 
WHERE   F431.PRDOCO = 401531
and     F431.PRMATC = 2
and     F43.PDLNTY = 'DC'

Group by 

     F43.PDDOCO, 
     F43.PDSFXO, 
     F43.PDLNID,
     F43.PDAREC, 
     F431.PRAREC/100
```

This query is still returning the two rows in the right table. Fairly new to SQL and struggling with the statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data it is difficult to tell where the problem might so I will offer a few suggestions that could help.

First, you are joining with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `PRODDTA.F4311` but you have in the `WHERE` clause a filter for that table. You should move the `F43.PDLNTY = 'DC'` to the JOIN condition. This is causing the query to act like an `INNER JOIN`.

Second, you can try using a subquery to get the `MAX(PRDOC)` value. Then you can limit the columns that you are grouping on which could eliminate the duplicates. The query would them be similar to the following:

```
SELECT F43.PDDOCO, 
  F43.PDSFXO, 
  F43.PDLNID,
  F43.PDAREC/100 As Received, 
  F431.PRAREC/100,
  F431.PRDOC
FROM PRODDTA.F43121 F431
INNER JOIN
(
  -- subquery to get the max
  -- then group by the distinct columns
  SELECT PDKCOO, max(PRDOC) MaxPRDOC
  FROM PRODDTA.F43121
  WHERE PRDOCO = 401531
    and PRMATC = 2
  GROUP BY PDKCOO
) f2
  -- join the subquery result back to the PRODDTA.F43121 table
  on F431.PRDOC = f2.MaxPRDOC
  AND F431.PDKCOO = f2.PDKCOO
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODDTA.F4311 F43
  ON F43.PDKCOO=F431.PRKCOO 
  AND F43.PDDOCO=F431.PRDOCO 
  AND F43.PDDCTO=F431.PRDCTO 
  AND F43.PDSFXO=F431.PRSFXO 
  AND F43.PDLNID=F431.PRLNID 
  AND F43.PDLNTY = 'DC'  -- move this filter to the join instead of the WHERE
WHERE F431.PRDOCO = 401531
  and F431.PRMATC = 2
```

If you provide your table structures and some sample data, it will be easier to determine the issue.